# Improving the performance of the titanic pattern

Tags: redis, zeromq

I am referring to the titanic pattern explained in the zeromq guide. Can someone please explain why it recommends not using a key-value store as compared to reading/writing disk files for persistence. Quoting from the guide:

```
"What I'd not recommend is storing messages in a database, not even a "fast" key/value    
store, unless you really like a specific database and don't have performance worries. You  
will pay a steep price for the abstraction, ten to a thousand times over a raw disk file."
```

There are other recommendations given in the guide, like storing the messages on to a disk file in a circular buffer fashion. But would it not be faster to store the messages, and retrieving them from a redis store? Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the zeromq guide, the example provided for this pattern uses simple files in a very naive way (using buffered I/O, without any fsync'ing). The broker is directly responsible of storing things on the filesystem. So the performance is mostly linked to the efficiency of the VFS and the filesystem cache. There is no real I/O in the picture.

In this context, the cost of an extra hop to store and retrieve the data into Redis will be very noticeable, especially if it is implemented using synchronous queries/replies.

Redis is very efficient as a remote key/value store, but it cannot compete with an embedded store (even a store implemented on top of a filesystem cache).